# After uninstall brew cannot install it back

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I could not update `brew update`. There was fatal error all the time. I di dnot use brew for years so I thought I'll uninstall it and then install back. I run

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

that went smoothly.

But after that when I try

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

It tells that

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

When I read how to install ruby it suggests `brew install ruby` but I have just uninstalled it.

I've searched over google and tried a lot of different commands but nothing works.

Comment: Try creating a new shell. The old Ruby was removed.

Comment: SOmehow ruby files are there and I was able to install brw by navigating to /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0 and run ruby command from there. After I installed brew I rune `brew install ruby` and everything back again.

Answer (score 1):

It's often the case that `bash` remembers where executables were in your path and if those are later removed it gets very confused. There's ways of [rehashing this](https://superuser.com/questions/490983/how-to-rehash-executables-in-path-with-bash) to update that, but creating a new shell usually fixes the issue just the same.

Specifying the full path to the system Ruby will also work.

Comment: This is why the Homebrew homepage says to use `/usr/bin/ruby` instead of `ruby`: http://brew.sh/